# Is it nessessory to have a facebook business manage account to work with WhatsApp Business API?

Tags: api

As a developer i would like to test WhatsApp Business API integration.. I am looking for a way to test WhatsApp Business API end points is there any way to test in a short and easy way without Verifying business account and using base-64 certificate as mentioned at Whatsapp Business API Getting Started at below URL,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp is now limited to providing APIs to the public. If you want to know how Whastaspp is working you can just go through any of the [Solution Providers](https://www.facebook.com/business/partner-directory). Because they proving sandbox for testing interfaces. In my knowledge, Whatsapp is not proving any sandbox or testing interface for the public. They are a global community of third-party solution providers with expertise on the WhatsApp Business API.